# How do I conditionly exclude coffescript comprehension items

Tags: arrays, coffeescript

I am sorting a dictionary using the following coffeescript

```
sortList: (list) ->
    keys = Object.keys(list).sort (a, b) -> list[b] - list[a]
    for name in keys
        {name, count: list[name]} if list[name] > 1
```

This produces an array where each item that has `list[name] > 1` is represented by a void value. You can see why if you look at the transpiled JS

```
FilterService.prototype.sortList = function(list) {
  var keys, name, _i, _len, _results;
  keys = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a, b) {
    return list[b] - list[a];
  });
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = keys.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    name = keys[_i];
    if (list[name] > 1) {
      _results.push({
        name: name,
        count: list[name]
      });
    } else {
      _results.push(void 0); <-- See the unwanted else clause here
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
```

I can get the result I want if I include a dummy `else` clause myself, like this:

```
sortList: (list) ->
    keys = Object.keys(list).sort (a, b) -> list[b] - list[a]
    for name in keys
        if list[name] > 1
            {name, count: list[name]}
        else
```

Now the unwanted generated `else` clause is empty and the resulting array does not contain any elements for `list[name] > 1`

Can you tell me how to correctly prevent the filtered items from appearing in the resulting array?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about filtering with the `when` keyword?

```
class StackExchange
  sortList: (list) ->
    keys = Object.keys(list).sort (a, b) -> list[b] - list[a]
    ({name, count: list[name]} for name in keys when list[name] > 1)
```

transpiles to

```
StackExchange.prototype.sortList = function(list) {
  var keys, name, _i, _len, _results;
  keys = Object.keys(list).sort(function(a, b) {
    return list[b] - list[a];
  });
  _results = [];
  for (_i = 0, _len = keys.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
    name = keys[_i];
    if (list[name] > 1) {
      _results.push({
        name: name,
        count: list[name]
      });
    }
  }
  return _results;
};
```

Comment: Aha - so coffeescript comprehensions allow for conditions via the `when` keyword. Perfect.